# A question about combinatorics: $\sum_{\substack{0\le k\le n\\ k\text{ even}}}\frac1{k+1}\binom nk$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

[image]

> Let $n\in\mathbb N$ be fixed. For $0\le k \le n$, et $C_k=\binom nk$. Evaluate: $$\sum_{\substack{0\le k\le n\\ k\text{ even}}} \frac{C_k}{k+1}.$$

My attempt  :  $(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}x^k}\implies \frac{(x+1)^{n+1}}{n+1}+C=\int (x+1)^ndx=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k+1}x^{k+1}}.$

Putting  $x=0$ we have  $C=\frac{-1}{n+1}$.

so my  answer is $$\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{n+1}$$

is its  True ?

Any hints/solution will  appreciated

thanks u

Comment: Did you consider that $k$ is even?

Comment: i thinks  its answer will  be  remain same  when k is even also  @harshit54

Comment: No it should not. If k is even then your are summing up $C_0+C_2+C_4+C_6......$. What you have summed is  $C_0+C_1+C_2+C_3......$.

Comment: When it comes to integration: $$\int_{-1}^1 x^k\,dx=0\qquad k\text{ odd}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution you have added all terms, whereas it should be done only for even ones:

$$\sum_{\substack{0\leq k \leq n\\k\text{ even}}}\frac 1{k+1}\binom nk=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac 1{k+1}\binom nk\left[\frac{x^{k+1}-(-x)^{k+1}}{2}\right]_0^1\\=\int_0^1\frac{(x+1)^n-(1-x)^n}{2}dx
=\frac{2^n}{n+1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint :
Observe that 
\begin{align*}
2\sum_{\substack{0\leq k \leq n\\k\text{ even}}} \frac{C_k}{k+1} &= \sum_{0\leq k\leq n} \frac{C_k}{k+1} +\sum_{0\leq k\leq n} \frac{C_k}{k+1} (-1)^k
\end{align*}

You can apply the rest of your reasoning to the two sums above to get your desired result.

Comment: can u elaborate  more ......??

Comment: This tricks permits to remove the "even" condition. having done that, these can be handled exactly as you did, actually you already did the first one and the second one is the same with $x=-1$